# Remove F-Curve Modifier from all selected keys in Graph Editor

Tags: animation, modifiers, fcurves

I added an F-Curve Modifier (**Shift Ctrl M**) to all selected Curves to repeat the animation.
[image: Add F-Curve Modifier (Shift Ctrl M)]

[image: Graph Editor]

Now I want to remove this F-Curve Modifier from all the selected Curves/Keys.
Is it possible to remove the F-Curve Modifier from all of them at ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it the same way you applied it
Go into the Graph Editor and select the keyframes that you wish to loop over (over their respective time period), press Shift + E, and select "Clear Cyclic (F-modifier)".

hope it helps somebody else (I just needed it myself)

[image]

Comment: That was fantastic, thank you! I had a bunch of accidentally-stacked modifiers, this eliminated them all at once! :-)